# mat datepicker styling is not showing

Tags: html, angular, bootstrap-4, angular-material

I used the mat datepicker but its style is not rendering in the web page

I tried add the styling to the styles.less

```
@import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css";
```

And import the MatNativeDateModule, MatFormFieldModule, MatInputModule in the app.module.ts

```
import { MatNativeDateModule, MatFormFieldModule, MatInputModule } from "@angular/material";
```

and

```
npm i @angular/cdk
```

and

```
ng add @angular/material
```

this is my code:

```
<input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker">
<mat-hint>MM/DD/YYYY</mat-hint>
<mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
<mat-datepicker #picker>
</mat-datepicker>
```

Comment: Update your imports to this instead: ```import {MatDatepickerModule} from '@angular/material/datepicker';``` then add it on your ```app.module.ts``` imports section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not only import the modules in your `app.module.ts` file, but also add them to your imports array of your module definition. You also did not yet import `MatDatepickerModule` so you should add this as well:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [ 
    BrowserModule, 
    FormsModule, 
    MatNativeDateModule, 
    MatDatepickerModule,
    MatFormFieldModule, 
    MatInputModule 
  ],
...
```